# Access to localhost script in Microsoft Edge when page is loaded using file protocol

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm attempting to load a script from a page that I've loaded into Microsoft Edge (20.10240) using the file protocol. In my < head > section I've got something like:

```
<script src="http://localhost:44300/Scripts/myscript.js"></script>
```

URL for the page is something like:

```
file:///C:/testpage.html
```

IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc. all work fine. Edge is the only one blocking this. I've checked the about:flags option to enable loopback addresses. And in fact, typing the script URL into the address bar works fine. This also works fine if I serve testpage.html up using http (e.g., http://localhost:44300/testpage.html). Also works fine from a page using the file protocol if the script is accessed using a remote URL. Seems to ONLY block localhost scripts if the page is loaded using the file protocol.

I'm assuming this is by design, but is there a way to make this work properly in Edge?

Thanks!